# Working with Array like JQuery objects's methods

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. I am having trouble working with array like jQuery objects's methods (I don't know if its right name) like `.height()` and `.animate()` which affect only the first element of what the query selector matches.

I do not know how to make them work with desired single element.

Like the 3rd element of what `$('li')` returns or loop into results of `$(li)` and get height of each.

Update:

Learnt that `$(this)[0] === this`

Comment: FYI there is no such thing as a 'jQuery array'. In this case, the array is a javascript construct.

Comment: Look into `.eq()` and `.each()` in the [API](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: And the `.map()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Like the 3rd element of what $('li') returns

For this, use `eq()`:

```
var $li = $('li').eq(3); // $li now contains the third li element
```

---

> loop into results of $(li) and get height of each.

For this, use `each()`:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).height());
});
```

Note that within the `each` function block, `this` refers to the DOM element of the current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through sets of elements via `.each` like so:

```
$(".someClass").each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height(); //height of current iterated elem
});
```

Or use `:eq` in a selector to get an element from a desired position:

```
$(".someClass:eq(3)").height(); //get elem at position 3
```